# Broadcast solve for triangular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, array-broadcasting

I have `k` triangular matrices of size `d x d`. For each one, I want to solve for `n` vectors (of dimension `d`).
As far as I know, `numpy.linalg.solve` allows me, using broadcasting, to perform all solves simultaneously. However, it uses Fortran's `GESV` and cannot utilize the triangular structure.
On the other hand, `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` seems to be able to handle triangular matrices, but not support multiple simultaneous solves.

Is there a way to achieve both?